# How to create Dynamic array of sshUserPrivateKey in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Error

> Could not instantiate
> {bindings=[@sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId=dev-02,keyFileVariable=dev-02-key),
> @sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId=dev-01,keyFileVariable=dev-01-key)]}
> for org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.BindingStep:
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.BindingStep.bindings
> expects
> java.util.List<org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.MultiBinding>
> but received class java.lang.String

I am trying to create sshUserPrivatekey value array in in jenkinsfile.
I am trying to create this array service_array and want to use in withCredentials but facing issue in that.

```
stages {

        stage('configure value') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def service_array=[]
                    def conjourString=""
                    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'stage') {
                        env.varible_host='stage'
                    } else if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'prod') {
                        env.varible_host='production'
                    } else if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'dev') {
                        env.varible_host='dev'
                    }else{
                        env.varible_host='dev'
                    }
                    
                    def listofserver = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/inventory/listofserver.json"
                    for(def i = 0;i<listofserver[env.varible_host].size();i++) {
                            println(listofserver[env.varible_host][i]);
                            def hostname=listofserver[env.varible_host][i]['host_name']
                            def keyString=hostname+"-key"
                            service_array.add(sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: hostname,
                                                    keyFileVariable: keyString));
                          
                        }
                        env.service_array=service_array
                }
            }
        },
        stage('Run Ansible Playbook Playbook') {
                steps {
                        echo "!* Running Ansible Playbook ${env.ANSIBLE_PB}. *!"
                        withCredentials(env.service_array) {
                        }
                    }
        }
 }
```

I am getting error in env.service_array, what can i use here?

Comment: When you place a parameter in the environment  (`env.service_array=service_array`) it is converted to string, and therefore the error. Instaed, just define the `service_array` without def - making it a global variable then use it as is: `withCredentials(service_array) {....`

Comment: This is solution. solved my issue.